# How to Refresh Data after Angular Update

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, angularjs

I'm adding data with this method:

```
.controller("addItemsController", function ($scope, $http) {
                var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('MyContacts')/items";
                var vm = $scope;
                var requestDigest = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                vm.addContact = function () {
                    return $http({
                        headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose", "X-RequestDigest": requestDigest, "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
                        method: "POST",
                        url: url,
                        data: {
                            'Title': vm.LastName,
                            'FirstName': vm.FirstName,
                            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.MyContactsListItem" }
                        }
                    })
                    .then(saveContact)
                    .catch(function (message) {
                        console.log("addContact() error: " + message);
                    });
                    function saveContact(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("Item Added Successfully");
                        return data.data.d;
                    }
                }
            })
```

What I want is to update the data on the page after adding the new item.

I've tried *$scope.contacts.push(data);* as suggested several places, but contacts comes back underfined.